# Why should we use "the" in "the political implications"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Which of the following expressions is correct?:

- *The political implications of ...*
- *Political implications of ...*

Is the *The* necessary here? When I search the web using Google, in most cases *The* is used. Here is an Ngram comparison of the two terms:

[image]

We can see from this that sentences starting with "The political implications of ... " are, according to these figures, over 10,000% more prevalent than sentences beginning with "Political implications of ... " in printed books available on Google. Why?

Comment: +1 Good question. Don't understand the close votes. Maybe they don't understand articles very well.

Comment: Your question had 4 close-votes. I put an Ngram in to illustrate the point. Hope that's OK. If not, feel free to do a roll-back! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria - Ngrams are case-sensitive. Your Ngram shows that the form with an article is more common **at the start of a sentence.** Also, I'd be very careful about saying something like _"X is 10,000% more prevalent than Y..."_. Data from Ngrams isn't always reliable – a famous line like Frost's "miles to go before I sleep" can really skew an Ngram's results. That all said, I applaud your efforts to help the O.P. and keep the question open.

Comment: @J.R. You're right about Ngrams in general - but wrong about the case sensitivity. The point of this question is surely that phrasal genitives are far more likely (much more than ten times/%10,000 in actual fact) to be definite than indefinite. The question itself does ask about these phrases at the beginning of a sentence, so the case-sensitivity makes the figures more pertinent. The figures shown actually biased *against* showing the true prevalence of definitely marked phrasal genitives, because the figures without *the* are not all genitive phrases, and many other forms of definite ...

Comment: @J.R.  ... determiner are excluded, for example *these* and so forth. :-)

Comment: A factor here might be whether this example sentence is in regular text or is in a title (such as in newspaper-ese). Newspaper-ese type of writing will often drop articles for space concerns.

Comment: @Araucaria - Wrong about case sensitivity? Then please explain [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+political+implications+of%2Cpolitical+implications+of%2Cthe+political+implications+of&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15), or run your Ngram again with the [case insensitive box checked](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+political+implications+of%2Cpolitical+implications+of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15). Also, wouldn't sentences w/ "The political implications of" be a **subset** of sentences with "political implications of"?

Comment: @J.R. The Q is about sentences *BEGINNING* with those phrases - therefore the capitalisation is important to find sentences *beginning* with those phrases. Secondly, let's say you want to rewrite the Qn to make it ask something else, presumably you want to make it about whether the phrase "political implications of" is usually preceded by "the". Well if you didn't try and restrict it like OP did, then, "political implications of" *would* be a subset of "the political implications of" and *FOR THAT VERY REASON*, we need sth like C-sensitivity to solve the subset problem! That's the point!

Comment: @J.R. So my point is, your point about Ngrams is pertinent, but your point about case sensitivity isn't - because case sensitivity is important for the results to be valid. I wrote a longer explanation before, when you didn't seem to be around, but I also said that I'd delete all my comments after the post was reopened, and because it was reopened, I did, before you came back, I think! Will write an answer hopefully tomorrow and delete my comments here - I don't really think the Ngram should be necessary for the question, but put it in to save the question for the benefit of users :)

Comment: @J.R. I'm happy to continue this conv in chat, if I'm still awake (it's 1am here ...)

Comment: @Araucaria - I see what you're getting at now, but this is the first time you or the O.P. mentioned anything about "sentences beginning with those phrases." (One could argue that can be inferred by the capitalization in the examples, but my comment was intended to make sure that was explicitly stated, not merely implied.) I've taken the liberty to edit the question one more time to make this discussion moot.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking or writing about [plural countable nouns] or [uncountable noun] *in general*, we (usually) don't use 'the':

> Political implications (in general) of corruption (in general) by politicians (in general) include ....

If we are talking about *specific* [plural countable nouns] or [uncountable noun], we (usually) use 'the':

> The (specific) political implications of the (specific) corruption by the (specific) politicians include ...

But it is also possible to mix 'the' and [no 'the']:

> The political implications of corruption by politicians include ...

might be talking about the *political* implications, compared to the *legal* implications etc.

Comment: Your first example doesn't sound very good without *the* before "Political" to my ear ...

Comment: Note that I said '(usually)' in my answer. Some people might use 'The' in my first example. I wouldn't.

Comment: @Sydney How about titles? I mean, in the title of something is *The* necessary? : 
The Political Implications of Russell's Thoughts, or without *The*?

Comment: Probably. "Russell's Thoughts" are specific thoughts, but names never have "The", but they lead to specific politic implications, so we would probably use "The". I agree with the 'usual-ness' of "The Political Implications of Russell's Thoughts".

Answer (score -1):

I think article "the" is neccessary here, because this phrase assumes, that here is exactly political implications and not any else. So, we should use "the".

Comment: *The* is only necessary when necessary. It is not always necessary, not even in this phrase. We would need a complete sentence to explain why *the* is used in the sentence or not.

Comment: @δοῦλος Can you give me an example whrer we would not need *the*, please.

Comment: "Political implications can be difficult to determine."  Using *the* would make that less general.

Comment: @MatthewRead Almost old bean, but the OP's question is about *The political implications **of***! The *of* here makes all the difference (although it's still possible, it's much less likely to have a null determiner with that *of* there. There's a reason for that!)

Comment: _Political implications of the DWI arrest won't be known for days._ No need for a "the" in that one, either.

Comment: @J.R. Hmmm, don't have the same grammaticality judgement on that as you at all. What do your buddies think? For me that's a definite no-no. Might be a pond thing, but I don't think so  ... (shrugs)

Comment: Political implications of ours are not necessarily true, are they @Araucaria?

Comment: @δοῦλος That's cheating, that's a different meaning of implication altogether

Comment: @Araucaria which is exactly why the question is best asked with accompanying example sentence(s). No one has defined *political implications* for the sake of this question

Comment: @δοῦλος Hey C'mon this ain't gladiator or something. If you can speak English, you know what kind of implications are being talked about here. Expecting the OP to clarify that's just silly. No one wants this site to work like that!

Comment: @Araucaria Would including an example sentence or two have improved the question? Even if only for native speakers who want to validate the meaning of words as used in a phrase out of any context by a non-native speaker?

Comment: @δοῦλος A native speaker wouldn't need a context for that phrase, imo

Comment: And you've been showed wrong. But more importantly, the inclusion of an example in order to provide more context *is* the way this site works.

Comment: @δοῦλος Was that last comment there meant for me as opposed to for Gremlin? Cos' you need to put the persons name in otherwise they won't get your comment. No, patently obvious meanings of words for example, are not meant to have to be stipulated for a question to work. It's only if the meaning is unclear ...